# Sending Starting Parameters to VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, named-pipes, windows-messages

I want to invoke Word App from my application, I have also created VSTO application to be hosted inside the word. I want to send starting parameters to the VSTO.
I want to show the side pane only if the it was invoked from my other application and automate the document accordingly.

How can i send initial parameters/ arguments to word panel

Comment: Launch word from your Application, then call your VSTO method to show up the pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a public method of your add-in. See [Calling Code in Application-Level Add-ins from Other Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx) for more information.